# Understanding of をだけを

Tags: grammar, particle-を, particle-だけ

In a comment on [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70597/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91-two-questions/70599#70599) it was pointed out that the combination "をだけ" appears a lot in a Google search, despite my thought that it was ungrammatical. On closer inspection it seems that many of these hits are of the form をだけを. Here's an example:

> 体重**をだけを**みてはいけない
>   It's no good if you're only looking out for your weight (*not sure about my translation*)

It seems to occur far too often for this to be a typo.

What's going on here?

Comment: I am surprised that there are many をだけを.

Comment: 「にだけに」「のだけの」「がだけが」とかも結構ヒットしますね・・

Comment: Bizarre... must be a typo but I don’t understand why there would be so many.

Comment: The initial number of about 1.4 million hits for をだけを -- and keep in mind, this applies to all Google searches in general -- is misleading. Navigating to the last page of results reveals [only about 120 hits](https://i.imgur.com/SguYsE4.gifv).

Comment: seconded; "をだけ" or "だけを" would be grammatical while this form is not. [少納言](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/) corpus lists 3 for "をだけ", 5090 for "だけを", and 0 for "をだけを".

Comment: @Setris でも、"をだけ" と "だけを" で同じようにやっても、最初は多いんですけど、最後のページまで行ったら、それぞれ「Page 14 of about 135 results」「Page 26 of about 251 results」になってしまうんです。。 "をだけを" が120なら、"だけを" や "をだけ" はもっと多くてもよさそうなのに。 いつも思うんですけど、グーグルって、こういうとこ、どうなってんですかね。。

Comment: ??? I have no search results like 「をだけを」 in Google search with Japanese as the primary language. Anyway 体重をだけをみてはいけない is totally broken and there's no translation for it. 体重だけをみてはいけない is valid.